# Mysql Duplicate entry 'xxxxxxxx' for key(unique) 'xxxxxxxxxx'

Tags: java, mysql

I have a problem of updating a row. I have a column called `serialNum` with `varchar(50) not null unique default null`

When I get the response data from the partner company, i will update the row according to the unique `serial_num` (our company's serial num).

Sometimes update failed because of :

```
Duplicate entry 'xxxxxxxx' for key  'serialNum'
```

But the value to update is not exists when i search the whole table. It happens sometimes, not always, like about 10 times out of 300.

Why does this happen and how can I solve it?

below is the query i use to update:

```
String updateQuery = "update phone set serialNum=?, Order_state=?, Balance=? where Serial_num=" + resultSet.get("jno_cli");
PreparedStatement presta = con.prepareStatement(updateQuery);
presta.setString(1, resultSet.get("oid_goodsorder"));
presta.setString(2, "order success");
presta.setFloat(3, Float.valueOf(resultSet.get("leftmoney")));
presta.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: MySQL is case insensitive by default. Could that be why it is finding duplicates?

Comment: Also beware of leading/trailing whitespaces

Comment: Show us the complete queries you are using to update and search.

Comment: Are you creating the querry yourself or are you using a library like hibernate to do so?

Comment: this project, i did not use any framework. i create the query myself

Comment: @Tagir Valeev i added the update query in the question. for the search, i use "select * from phone where serialNum='xxxxxxxx'" in the mysql workbench, and it returns 0 row(s)

Comment: Are there two records with the same "Serial_num"? If there are, the update would end up setting the "serialNum" of those two records to the same value, breaking the constraint. By the way, having one column called Serial_num and another called serialNum sounds like a disaster waiting to happen.

Comment: @Joni the Serial_num is unique as well

Comment: can you `show create table phone`, perhaps there are constraints we don't know of?

Comment: Can you share phone table structure and and records in the database in the moment of update executing following query: "select * from phone where Serial_num=" + resultSet.get("jno_cli")

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is in `resultSet.get("oid_goodsorder")` where did you get this result? is 'oid_goodsorder' is unique?  Did you always updates whole table?

If **oid_goodsorder** is unique, it is possible to have duplicates in `serialNum`, because you don't use bulk update, instead you update every record separately, therefore it is possible:
Before:
**serialNum=11,22,33,44
oid_goodsorder=44,11,22,33**

It tries to update first `serialNum` to 44, but 44 is exists! 
But if you finish all update `serialNum` will be unique...

1. If you wants to get error rows you could disable set `serialNum` is not unique and check table for duplicating `serialNum`
2. If you don't have duplicating values try to use bulk update
   [Java - how to batch database inserts and updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13843631/java-how-to-batch-database-inserts-and-updates)